# Different distributions - original and imputed values

Tags: multiple-imputation

I have performed chained multiple imputation in Stata and performed 2 robustness checks to compare distribution of the original and imputed values
Visual exploration
Kolmogorov-Smirnov test of equality of distributions

Visual exploration is
[image]

I notice that whereas the mean of the distributions are similar (dotted green line superimposed on the continuous red line), standard deviation seems a bit different and am wondering whether there’s a way to try and address this.

Thanks in advance!